# MSBuild Specify .NET Core Web App wwwroot output files (Minified Only)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, msbuild

I have a .net core web application.  I'm taking advantage of bundling both my css and js files.  I'd like it so, after I build, the non minified files are not copied into the release folder.  The idea is not to publish files that aren't going to actually be used.  I've always relied on default behavior so I'm curious how I can control the output of my build and thus creating lighter weight packages.

Comment: If you don't want it to be automatically copied, take them out of the wwwroot folder. Otherwise, you'll have to exclude them manually

Comment: I was thinking of that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this in your csproj file to exclude files from the publish output:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <NonMinifiedFiles Include="wwwroot\**\*.js;wwwroot\**\*.css" 
                    Exclude="**\*.min.js;**\*.min.css" />
  <Content Update="@(NonMinifiedFiles)" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Much appreciated.